# Getting an error for android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: android, android-library

I'm getting an error in xml file. Any idea what i have done wrong?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.dusandimitrijevic.genres.NotifyingScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
            />

        <!-- Here i'm getting an error -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">



                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"

                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/title"

                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="30sp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="italic"
                        android:id="@+id/titleShortDescription"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"

                        android:textSize="19sp"/>
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/titleImage"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                            android:scaleType="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/horor" />

                    </FrameLayout>

                </LinearLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/titleDescription"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"


            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">



                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="#424242">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Contact"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>



                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Naman Dwivedi"
                                android:textStyle="italic"
                                android:padding="15dp"
                                android:id="@+id/textContact"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="25sp"/>



                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="namandwivedi14@gmail.com"
                        android:id="@+id/textEmail"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">




                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Send Email"
                    android:id="@+id/textSendEmail"
                    android:textColor="#fea016"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



    </LinearLayout>

</com.dusandimitrijevic.genres.NotifyingScrollView>
```

And this is the error:

error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardPreventCornerOverlap' in package 'com.dusandimitrijevic.hororfilmovi_analizeiocene'

Comment: Probably not the cause, but you have several unused namespaces `xmlns:card_view`

Comment: I have removed those and still geting an error. And to mention i have imported library cardView.

Comment: Does it only happen with `cardPreventCornerOverlap` ? Or do you get an error on your next line if you remove that?

Comment: app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" When i remove those two i'm not getting an error anymore, but i think i need them for getting this effect i want.

Comment: Just in case, which support.v7 version are you using? It might just be an older one that didn't have the property.

Comment: I'm using appcompat v7 and android-support-v7-cardview

Comment: Go it, but which version? For instance, the dependency `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'` would mean you are using version 22.2.0 . Do not confuse the support minimum level (7), with the actual version of the release.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. Where could i see what version i'm using?

Comment: Then you have your dependency on come jar file somewhere. It probably has the version in its name, like "support-v4-22.2.0". I would strongly suggest you use gradle. Manually managing dependencies is too error prone.

Comment: I can see that in other libraries, but in this i can only see android-support-v7-cardview and nothing else.